# Kill a process created in a different class

Tags: java, process

Say I run a program in my `Process` class, something like:

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("setup.exe");
try {
    p1.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //Whatever
}
```

And then I also have a cancel button in my `GUI` class, something along the lines of:

```
private void cancelButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Need to interrupt the thread from here!
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Simply exiting the program out as is leaves my setup.exe process I created over in `Process.java` running, and that's a problem. Normally I'd call `p1.destroy()`, but I'm having issues making the connection in between the two classes.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

```
private void beginThread() {
        SwingWorker<String, Void>  myWorker = new SwingWorker<String, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
                //Do some stuff
            }
        return null;
        }
    };
    myWorker.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your run the process in a separate thread, you can call `processThread.interrupt()` from your GUI class.

You then simply need to modify the try/catch to:

```
try {
    p1.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Sys.err(e.toString());
    //don't ignore the exception:
    p1.destroy();
    Thread.currentThread.interrupt(); //reset interrupted flag
}
```

Comment: Your assumption is right. Couple questions, though. First, since I've never used `interrupt()` before, is this going to otherwise affect any other programs or processes that run later on in the thread? I'm going to need to repeat this whole thing with a number of other processes as well, as I run about half a dozen in total. The second question, what's wrong with pushing a quick log of the exception? Thanks!

Comment: @JTApps my comment meant: when you get an interruption, don't ignore it. You can log it of course!

Comment: When you call `someThread.interrupt()` you set that thread's interrupted flag to true. That's it. It is then that thread's responsibility to do something with it. In your case, `p1.waitFor()` throws an `InterruptedException` when it detects that the thread in which it is running has been interrupted and you can decide to ignore it or do something with it. Resetting the interrupted flag is good practice if, for example, your code is run in an executor. If it is a stand alone thread and there are no more instructions after the catch block, then it is essentially a no-op.

Comment: I ended up running into a problem. This is my first time working with multiple threads, so please bear with me. I added some additional code to my original post. It's the thread where this process is running, and it seems like that's the one I want to interrupt. However, nothing I've tried thus far has let me interrupt the thread from my cancel button method. They are both in the same class, I should add.

Comment: @JTApps Avoid using the suppress warnings thingy: fix your code instead: `SwingWorker<String, Void> myWorker= new SwingWorker<String, Void>() { ...}`.

Comment: is `//do some stuff` where you launch the process?

Comment: It launches a method in a separate class, which in turn contains the above code that launches the process.

Comment: @JTApps But do you launch a separate thread manually or is it handled by the SwingWorker?

Comment: I'm going to assume it's handled by the SwingWorker. I don't create additional threads or modify the thread itself at any point after the initial creation.

Comment: In that case you simply need to keep a reference to `myWorker` in your class that you can use from your `cancelButtonActionPerformed` method, and call `myWorker.cancel(true);` to interrupt the underlying task.

Comment: Alright, that cleared up everything. I have my code currently exactly as you've described it. The only remaining problem is that, once the process is killed, the thread proceeds onto the rest of the code and throws interruptedExceptions on each of them before finally exiting the program. Any idea what's up there? I've given you the answer check anyway, so  you don't have to answer. I just wanted to ask.

Comment: @JTApps difficult to say without knowing what code throws the exception. But if you simply add a `throws Exception` to the method called from `doInBackground`, for example, then exceptions will bubble up: you need to handle them appropriately. You might want to post more code to show the issue (possibly in a different question as this thread is becoming a little cluttered!)

Comment: Good idea on starting a new thread, and I'll do that if this last bit doesn't help. Basically, I have that same method (that contains the process p1) lined up half a dozen times, and each one is basically the exact same. When I hit cancel, I get an exception from all of them, which is basically the problem.

Comment: @JTApps You could start each method with a `if(Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) return;` - but that seems a bit ugly. Alternatively, rethrow the InterruptedException: `p1.destroy(); throw e;` and add a try/catch (InterruptedException e) in the `doInbackground` method around all your methods calls. When one of the methods throws IE, it will be caught and the others won't be executed.

Comment: Figured it out. After I kill the process, I have to "System.exit(0)` in order to immediately kill the thread and program. It has to go in with the exception handling, otherwise the thread hits the exception and just moves on.